# Network Policy for "kube-node-lease" in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Newbie here.
I have a nginx pod in namespace **isolation**, which is accessible only by a namespace with label **env:test** which apparently is the **test** namespace. Here is my **.yaml**:

```
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: allow-different-namespace-policy
  namespace: isolation
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          env: test
```

So what happens if my pod **dies**? I guess **kube-node-lease** namespace won't have access to my pod, so if anything bad happens it won't be restarted. What is considered best practice to **grant access**? Labeling is an option, but is there something else I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So what happens if my pod dies?

if it's Deployed as **kind:Deployment** it will get restarted and start running again if there is no error.

> I guess kube-node-lease namespace won't have access to my pod

True

there is no relation between **kube-node-lease** and POD restart, but if anything happens to one of the Node POD will get auto restated or shifted to another node. it's best option to run multiple PODs of Nginx like 3-4.

**labeling** is a good option for granular level access you can also use the **POD** level instead of the namespace label.

```
- podSelector:
            matchLabels:
              role: frontend
```

**IP blocks**

```
- from:
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 172.17.0.0/16
            except:
              - 172.17.1.0/24
```

Ref doc : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/